# overstating field size in database design

Tags: sql-server

I have some fields for my tables that are strings and at the moment, most of the field size have pretty high character limits. For instance, 100 char for the street name. Is there a penalty for using large field size? If I change the limit to 30 char for this field for instance, will there be a performance gain or an efficiency with size? There would about 50 fields that could be candidates for shrinkage.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: For char, the space is always used in the database, but for varchar, while the penalty will be less, the need to have larger space set aside during operations they you really need may also still make it a little less efficient. I wouldn't worry about varchar columns unless they are very large - like always using varchar(max) or varchar(1000).

Comment: You should be mindful of going over the size of one page (8k) since it will impact performance. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518922/how-big-can-a-sql-server-row-be-before-its-a-problem

Comment: Given the low cost of hard drives, I'd not worry about efficiency of storage these days. As JNK says, there is an impact on indexing for very large fields - that's definitely worth bearing in mind. The pain of changing an application because you allocated too little space is far greater than the cost of a few extra bytes in your database table.

Comment: I think ignoring storage because it is cheap is a bad idea.  Every byte on disk needs to be fetched and processed, and the slowest part of almost every SQL Server installation is the disk storage.  **Less bytes = faster queries.**

Comment: True - but not so as you'd notice in most real world situations I've encountered. On the other hand, re-writing an application because you've been too stingy with column widths causes real, measurable pain - I've got the scars to prove it.
If you use VARCHAR, you only retrieve the data entered, and if the business domain includes addresses that are 100 characters long, restricting that width for performance reasons seems a poor trade-off to me.

Comment: I may be biased because of the data I work with, but when you have a 2 TB table with 1b rows, saving 10 bytes per row adds up quickly and makes a noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: Yeah, at extremes - 2TB counts as extreme in my book - you have to go for extreme optimizations.

Comment: @Neville: I'd be careful about saying, "Hey, what's an extra 10 bytes these days?" 10 bytes is almost nothing, but 10 bytes times 10 million records is definately something. That said, I agree that one should be very careful about making fields smaller than a legitimate requirement out of fear of using too much disk space. It's great to say, "I'm going to buy a small, fuel-efficient car to save gas". But if you have ten kids, this is not a viable plan.

Comment: @Jay - 10 bytes times 10 million records is around 100MB - still not something I'd worry about. Yes, there are cases where storage is important - at extreme scale, or on constrained devices, for instance. I don't think they apply to the original question though.
If I had to chose how to spend my software development time, I would not go shrinking database columns in order to save disk space...

Comment: If the 100MB causes 20% less data to fit in a 512MB disk controller cache, it will absolutely matter (voice of experience).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're talking about `varchar` and `nvarchar` then no, there is no penalty for allowing a higher field length.

---

*Some caveats to bear in mind, though:*

- **There is a 2 byte overhead per row for variable length fields** (per field).  If you have a very short field it may make more sense to use a `CHAR`.  `Varchar(2)` for instance actually uses between 2-4 bytes per row, while `CHAR(2)` always uses 2.
- **Very long fields cannot be indexed.**  The maximum length for all fields in an index key set is 900 bytes.
- **If you allow more data than you expect, you will eventually get unexpected results.**  If you allow 100 characters for a street name, at some point other data is likely to get into that field without you being aware of it (for instance the entire address).  If you had it appropriately sized, you would likely get an error on insert instead.
- **Allowing very wide rows could lead to page splits and fragmentation.**  If you have a row longer than 8k it will need to be split onto multiple data pages.  A lot of these can really hurt performance.  **Narrower in general is more efficient.**

Comment: You could add caveats in shortening as well to this answer e.g. make sure that column is at least large enough: address varchar(30) cannot cope with _Bolderwood Arboretum Ornamental Drive_ or _Northeast Kentucky Industrial Parkway_.

Comment: @Aleksi - very true.  I think those are more obvious, though, which is why OP is using wide fields to begin with.

Comment: "at some point other data is likely to get into that field without you being aware of it" An interesting point. I've seen plenty of systems where users took any field that was not applicable to the present record as a general-purpose comment field.

Comment: [There can be a penalty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000/5654947#5654947)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, "Is there a penalty for declaring the field size bigger than any values that are actually stored in it?", then as long as it is declared varchar, the answer is no. Every SQL DB engine that I know of stores only the number of characters actually given in the data (plus a length value). So if you define the field as varchar(100) but only store 10 characters in it, then it will only take up 10 characters on disk (plus 2 bytes or so for the length). When in doubt, I routinely make my varchar fields ridiculously large.

If you mean, "Is there a penalty for storing long character fields," the answer is yes. Disk space today is cheap, but it's not free, so you don't want to waste it for no reason. Probably more important, it takes time to read data off the disk, so the longer your data fields are, the slower the program becomes. If the field is indexed, this can really slow down your retrievals, as every read is going to have to compare the key value against this big long field.

Bear in mind that if you give the user a big data entry field, they will use it, sooner or later.

All that said, I'd err on the side of too big rather than too small. Disk space is cheap enough that you don't want to force users to invent abbreviations on the fly because they can't fit the real data into the available field. The system I'm working on today has a product description field that is too small for many of the real names of our products, so users have to abbreviate. And of course every user abbreviates differently, so we have twenty different ways to say the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Anybody claiming that there is no penalty for declaring a field size bigger than what is actually going to be stored in the table is incorrect.  The actual size of the data (plus that 2 byte overhead) is what actually gets stored, but it's the column definition that is used to determine the estimate as far as the execution plan goes.  So, while declaring a varchar(1000) to store a 10 character value will only eat up 12 characters of disk space, the execution plan estimates will be much less efficient and negative skew the results, for both how much memory to grant the operation and whether or not the operation can be performed solely in memory or whether it'll require tempdb drive space as well. You may make your column varchar(1000), but the engine doesn't know that all of your stored values are really less than varchar(10), so the engine estimates defensively and allocates work space based on an average approximation of what could be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Field length checking is something you get 'for free', meaning you don't have to use a `CHECK` constraint to do the same. And you don't want oversized data values when, for example, you have to upload your data to another database that has limited the same data element to 35 characters in line with the international standard address.